# SQL query with having

Tags: sql, having

I've some problems with understanding how `having` works. It's clear to me when I check the count of something, but is this the only use case for it?

For example I have a `tasks` table and `tasks_parameters` table which have got columns: `key`, `value`, `task_id`. Now, I would like to select all `tasks` which have got two parameters:

```
key = 'type' && value = 'work'
key = 'priority' && value = 'normal'
```

I was thinking about that query:

```
select t.id from tasks t
join tasks_parameters p on (p.task_id=t.id)
group by t.id, p.key, p.value
having p.key = 'type' and p.value = 'work' and
       p.key = 'priority' and p.value = 'normal';
```

but, ofcourse, it doesn't work, because `parameter` can't have two diffrent values for the `key`. Is it even possible to query something like this?

Comment: Not sure if I'm on the right track here on what you would like to achieve, but would this work: `HAVING (p.key = 'type' and p.value = 'work') OR (p.key = 'priority' and p.value = 'normal');`

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  But, you need two changes:

- Remove `key` and `value` from the `group by`.
- Change the `having` to use `sum()` instead of the unaggregated values.

The resulting query looks like:

```
select t.id
from tasks t join
     tasks_parameters p
      on p.task_id = t.id
group by t.id
having sum(case when p.key = 'type' and p.value = 'work' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when p.key = 'priority' and p.value = 'normal' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `having` clause takes place *after* the `group by`.  The `sum()` counts the number of rows that match each condition.

Comment: You're missing some equality comparison in your having clause, don't you ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus . . . Yes, it was missing.  Thank you.  (Ironically, it still would have worked in some databases, but that definitely was not my original intention.)

Answer (score 0):

The `having` clause is for filtering on aggregate results.  To filter on field values, use a `where` clause.

```
select t.id 
from tasks t join tasks_parameters p on p.task_id=t.id
where (p.key = 'type' and p.value = 'work')
or
(p.key = 'priority' and p.value = 'normal');
```